# how to run superserver on localhost?

Tags: supertest, apache-superset

Very close to using superset on windows 10. How do I configure superset to run on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0?

(Python34) E:\Miniconda3\Scripts>fabmanager run --app superset
    2018-02-24 15:25:59,755:INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
    2018-02-24 15:26:07,469:WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
    2018-02-24 15:26:07,475:INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 767-541-664
    2018-02-24 15:26:07,513:INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Answer (score 0):

It already is running on localhost. Just you can also  access it from other machines in the same network

See [Flask AppBuilder](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

> `fabmanager run`
>
> You now have a running development server on http://localhost:8080.